# Symfony HttpFoundation Request getBaseUrl() vs getBasePath()

Tags: php, symfony, silex

What is the difference between [getBaseUrl](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getBaseUrl) and [getBasePath](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getBasePath) of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request? I'd like to know when to use one over the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getBaseUrl also includes the scripts filename.

The phpDoc comments give you further explaination:

getBasePath:

```
/**
 * Returns the root path from which this request is executed.
 *
 * Suppose that an index.php file instantiates this request object:
 *
 *  * http://localhost/index.php         returns an empty string
 *  * http://localhost/index.php/page    returns an empty string
 *  * http://localhost/web/index.php     returns '/web'
 *  * http://localhost/we%20b/index.php  returns '/we%20b'
 ...
```

getBaseUrl:

```
/**
 * Returns the root URL from which this request is executed.
 *
 * The base URL never ends with a /.
 *
 * This is similar to getBasePath(), except that it also includes the
 * script filename (e.g. index.php) if one exists.
 ...
```

Comment: I did but when you look at the outcome for something like http: //localhost/web/ you'll get the same result. Thanks I didn't catch the phpdoc comments.

Comment: In prod env it's the same in this case, app.php is omitted.

Comment: You should mark this answer or the answer below as the correct one.

Answer (score -2):

`getBasePath()` will return you folders to you php script:
*/CoreBundle/Controller/*

`getBaseUrl()` will return you folders AND the script:
*/CoreBundle/Controller/ClientController.php*

Comment: Incorrect, it has nothing to do with the script path